# On the product of analytic functions

Tags: analytic-functions

Let $f,g:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be analytic. It is well known that the product $h:=fg$ is then also analytic.

I would like to prove it by a using the following characterization of analyticity:
$h$ is analytic if and only if, for any compact $K \subset (0,1)$, there exists $C>0$ such  that
$$|h^{(n)}(x)| \leq C^{n+1} n!$$
for any $x \in K$ and $n \geq 0$.
My attempt:
$$
|h^{(n)}|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}\right|
\leq \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} C^{n-k+1} (n-k)! C^{k+1} k!
=C^{n+2} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (n-k)! k!
=C^{n+2} (n+1)!
$$
I have n+1 instead of n...

Comment: f and g wont necessarily have the same limiting constant

Comment: @K.defaoite   Yes but you can take the max of the two constants

Comment: I don't see any mistake in your work. I suppose your upper bound just isn't tight enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion. The terms in the Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent series can be estimated by first normalizing the two series so they both sum to 1. (They are now  essentially probability distributions.) Then you can see that each individual term in the Cauchy product (the convolution of the two distributions) must be uniformly bounded by 1.

In more detail, given functions $f$ and $g$ and their product $h=fg$, choose a slightly new constant $C$  so that

$a_n=\frac{f^n}{n! C^n}$ satisfies $a_n\leq .9^n$  and likewise

$b_n= \frac{g^n}{n! C^n}$ satisfies $|b_n|\leq .9^n$

Then you want to estimate the behavior of

$ c_n= \frac{ h^n}{n! C^n} $ which satisfies  the algebraic identity $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k} b_k$.

Now put absolute values across this expression and use the absolute summability suggestion to complete the proof.

Comment: I don't see the link with my question, can you be more explicit with maybe some computations ?